# Translate SQL Server query to Postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-migration

I got stuck on translating this SQL Server query to Postgres query.

SQL Server Query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.JSON_VALUE', N'FN') IS NULL
                        BEGIN
                            DECLARE @sql varchar(1000)

                         SET @sql = 'CREATE FUNCTION DBO.JSON_VALUE(@pjson nvarchar(2000), @ppath nvarchar(2000))
                          RETURNS NVARCHAR(2000)
                            WITH SCHEMABINDING
                          AS
                          BEGIN
                            return JSON_VALUE(@pjson, @ppath)
                          END'
                           EXEC(@sql)
                        END
```

I'm experienced in SQL Server but not in Postgres, so some help would be needed.
 
I've managed to translate this @sql = '..' function inside marks to Postgres, so here in code is okay.
I just need to translate other part and to have successfully running query.

Comment: Looks this can be simplified to `create function if not exists ...`

Comment: What is the purpose of the function to start with? It does not seem to make a lot of sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , I can do it like this: https://pastebin.com/48AkqJi4, but do I need to execute that function? If yes, can I do it from postgres query, like here in SQL Server it is EXEC(@sql)?

Comment: Why do you need to dynamically create the function?

Comment: @Parfait I'm using this function as User Defined Function (UDF) in code, it get's called on startup. But since we are migrating to Postgres from Sql Server, I need to translate it to Postgres